# I want to use the wait function in the script of HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm an app developer.

I would like to display `og:title` with the title obtained through firebase communication in script.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!--title>Investing People</title-->
   <!--script type="text/javascript" src="share.js"></script-->
    <meta property="og:title" content="채팅방 공유" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="이미지를 클릭하여 채팅방에 참여하세요" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content=""/>

    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js" integrity="sha256-HwWONEZrpuoh951cQD1ov2HUK5zA5DwJ1DNUXaM6FsY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="share.js"></script>
    <script async>
        var _url = new URL(location.href);
        var _urlParams = _url.searchParams;
        var _code = _urlParams.get('code');

        if(_code == null || _code == '') {
            location.href='https://localhost:5000';
        } else {
            var title = getRoomTitle(_code);
            if(title != null) {
                var _result = title + ' 방을 공유합니다';
                document.title = _result;
                 $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", _result);
                // alert(value);
                console.log('title = '+ _result);
                console.log('미리보기 제목 = '+ document.querySelector("meta[property='og:title']").getAttribute("content"));
            } else {
               location.href='https://localhost:5000';
            }

            /*var _title = getRoomTitle(_code).then((value) => {
            var _result = value + ' 방을 공유합니다';
                document.title = _result;
                $("meta[property='og\\:title']").attr("content", _result);
                console.log('title = '+ _result);
                console.log('img path = '+ document.querySelector("meta[property='og:title']").getAttribute("content"));
            });*/
             console.log('script 끝');
        }
    </script>
<body>
<a>잠시만 기다려주세요.</a>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

The `getRoomTitle()` function is inside **share.js**.

```html
async function getRoomTitle(roomNo) {
  var value = await db.collection('TALK').doc(roomNo).get();
  if(value.data() != null) {
       var _data = value.data();
       var title = _data['title'];
       console.log('_data= ' + _data['title']);
       return title;
  } else {
      console.log('collection select error');
      return '';
  }
}
```

Script End log is being taken and the log inside `getRoomTitle()` is being taken.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Any errors being logged in the console?

Comment: If you put await in front of getRoomTitle() inside the script of html, the following error occurs. 
====> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Just as it says, `await` can only be used in async functions and at the top level of modules. You could wrap the entire `if/else` block in an async function and call the function at the end.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You could try await:

```
var title = await getRoomTitle(_code);
```

Comment: The following error occurs. => Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: So your getRoomTitle returns a valid String?

Comment: Returns a valid string, but cannot continue due to an error.

Comment: Can you post the error? To clear up: The error occurs without the await statement?

Comment: If await is not used: returns [object Promise].
When using await: "Uncaught SyntaxError: wait is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules" error occurs.

Comment: The line `var title = await getRoomTitle(_code);` must be called in an async function. Try: `async function run() {var title = await getRoomTitle(_code); console.log(title);} run();`

Comment: Thank you ! However, it returns normally, but does not apply to og:title after the script is terminated. Do you know how?